# Merge/Join/Combine dictionaries with same key inside a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have list of dictionaries

```
rows = [{'sku':123,'barcode':99123,'day_1_qty':9,'store':118},
        {'sku':123,'barcode':99123,'day_1_qty':7,'store':109},
        {'sku':124,'barcode':99124,'day_1_qty':9,'store':118},
        {'sku':123,'barcode':99123,'day_2_qty':10,'store':118}....]
```

I want merge them and this is my desired output:

```
rows = [{'sku':123,'barcode':99123,'day_1_qty':9,'store':118,'day_2_qty':10},
        {'sku':123,'barcode':99123,'day_1_qty':7,'store':109},
        {'sku':124,'barcode':99124,'day_1_qty':9,'store':118},....]
```

tried merging them by sku but the other store wont show please help

```
def generate_oos(dict_list):
    res = map(lambda dict_tuple: dict(ChainMap(*dict_tuple[1])),
        groupby(sorted(dict_list,key=lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["SKU"]),
                key=lambda sub_dict: sub_dict["SKU"]))

    return list(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
rows = [
    {"sku": 123, "barcode": 99123, "day_1_qty": 9, "store": 118},
    {"sku": 123, "barcode": 99123, "day_1_qty": 7, "store": 109},
    {"sku": 124, "barcode": 99124, "day_1_qty": 9, "store": 118},
    {"sku": 123, "barcode": 99123, "day_2_qty": 10, "store": 118},
]

tmp = {}
for d in rows:
    tmp.setdefault((d["sku"], d["store"]), []).append(d)

out = []
for k, v in tmp.items():
    out.append({})
    for vv in v:
        out[-1].update(vv)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {
        "sku": 123,
        "barcode": 99123,
        "day_1_qty": 9,
        "store": 118,
        "day_2_qty": 10,
    },
    {"sku": 123, "barcode": 99123, "day_1_qty": 7, "store": 109},
    {"sku": 124, "barcode": 99124, "day_1_qty": 9, "store": 118},
]
```